# How to get data from REST api using an API key in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest, authentication

I am using a 3rd party REST API in my node server. The 3rd party API provider as given me an API key and an example in cURL as follows:

```
$ curl -u APIKey@https://xyzsite.com/api/v1/users
```

I am not sure how I do it in node js. I have tried following but no luck. I get

```
var options = {
  host: "xyzsite.com",
  path: "/api/v1/users",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + myAPIKey
  }
};


https.get(options, function(res, error) {
  var body = "";
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {

    console.log(body);
  });
  res.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  });
});
```

Console message

```
{
  "message": "No authentication credentials provided."
}
```

Comment: What API are you using? You're either not supplying the correct credentials or your request contains errors.

Answer (score 1):

Change your request like this..

```
https.get(myAPIKey + "@https://xyzsite.com/api/v1/users",function(res,error){
  var body = "";
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {

    console.log(body);
  });
  res.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  });
});
```

Or, if you want to use the `options` object..

```
var options={
  host:"xyzsite.com",
  path:"/api/v1/users",
  auth: myAPIKey
};


https.get(options,function(res,error){
  var body = "";
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {

    console.log(body);
  });
  res.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
  });
});
```

[More info on NodeJs https options](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately, it did not work. The first approach threw Error: Unable to determine the domain name. And the second one the same error, No authentication credentials provided.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'd have to know more about the API to determine why it's not working.